# Does resetting FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS to 1 checks for consistency

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

let's say i have something like this:

```
start transaction;
set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
insert into ...;
set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
commit;
```

does this guarantee the consistency of the informations inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not check the added data

> Enabling foreign_key_checks does not trigger a scan of table data, which means that rows added to a table while foreign_key_checks is disabled are not checked for consistency when foreign_key_checks is re-enabled.

See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-checks

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

As mysql manual on [foreign key constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says on re-enabling `foreign_key_check` setting (emphasis added):

> Enabling foreign_key_checks does not trigger a scan of table data, which means that rows added to a table while foreign_key_checks is disabled are **not checked for consistency when foreign_key_checks is re-enabled**.